# Javascript File Not Functioning in Wordpress w/ Proper Enqueueing in Functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, themes

My JS file is being properly called in my functions.php file because there is no error in the console when I inspect element. Why is this js code not running? Do I need to wrap the function? Everything I tired did not work. I am no js expert, but I think this code should work... It worked in my codepen.

Note: I am calling the script in the footer. Should I be calling it in my header since it is for my mobile header menu?

```
// Mobile Menu

$('.hamburger').on('click', function () {

    $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');

});
```

Comment: Do you have "hamburger" as the class on the button? Do you have "main-navigation" as the class on the menu element?

Comment: yeah :P let me double check spelling

Comment: I am getting an error now Uncaught type error: $ is not a function

Comment: Then you are missing jQuery or it is not loaded before your script loads.

Comment: I am loading jquery before my script :P

Comment: If that were the case, you wouldn't be getting that error -- unless you are loading it and called `noConflict()` on it, in which case you can't use `$` and have to use `jQuery` instead wherever you have a dollar sign. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: It says in console above the error in my js file, jqmimigrate: migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

Comment: it says anonymous function then @ myscript.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine via the footer.  You could try wrapping it in a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.hamburger').on('click', function () {
      $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
   });
});
```

How are you calling the jQuery?  Are you placing it in a shortcode to a function in your functions.php, or directly in a  tag inside the footer?

Last question (sorry, i'm new - and thorough): Have you checked your console? Any other Java errors?

- sorry this is a mess, I am trying to figure out the formatting for answers/comments

Comment: no other errors. I changed the $ to jQuery and now I am getting no errors in console, but the menu is still not working. Let me look into the css

Comment: I am calling it in functions.php and placing in footer

Comment: View your source - is the code actually being outputted to the footer when you load the page?  Sometimes i've had to use ob_start(); and return with functions in Wordpress rather than ?> or echo statements.

Comment: Not sure of my versions of jquery off the top of my head...try:


`$( ".hamburger" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
});`

If it works i'll edit my original answer.

Comment: Otherwise you could use an each statement:
`$('.hamburger').on('click', function () {
 $('.main-navigation').each(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('open');
        });
});`

Comment: problem was what you said from the start. I have two menus one for mobile one for desktop. main-navigation and mobile-navigation. If you look, I had to change main to mobile lol. But the real fix was changing the $ to jQuery as that got rid off all errors